# So, I am trying to restrict a slash command to a certain role. I am using nextcord.H

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I am trying to make a slash command (`/test`) and I am getting a TypeError.

My code:

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord.utils import get

client=nextcord.Client(intents=nextcord.Intents.all())

@client.slash_command(name="test")
async def test(interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
  if interaction.user in get(interaction.guild.roles, name="Test Role"):
    await interaction.send("You have this role!")
  else:
    await interaction.send("You do not have this role.")
client.run("token")
```

The error:

```py
if interaction.user in get(interaction.guild.roles,name='Test Role'):
TypeError: argument of type 'Role' is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Hope you can help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states it is returning a single varible ie `Test Role` and not a iterable, what you should do is check for the role within the user's roles something like this:

```
@client.slash_command(name="test")
async def test(interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
  role = nextcord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="Test Role")
  if role in interaction.user.roles:
    await interaction.send("You have this role!")
  else:
    await interaction.send("You do not have this role.")
```

Comment: Yup, I already figured that out but that's correct!